# Compute rank of Matrix

Tags: c++, c, matrix, rank

I need to calculate rank of 4096x4096 sparse matrix, and I use C/C++ code.
I found some libraries (like Armadillo) that do it but they're too slow (almost 5 minutes).

I've also tried two Open Source version of Matlab (Freemat and Octave) but both crashed when I tried to make a test with a script.

5 minutes isn't so much but I must get rank from something like a million of matrix so the faster the better.

Someone knows a fast library for rank computation?

Comment: Mhhh, I don't think. Thank's I try it now.

Comment: that being said, i don't remember if it supports sparse matrix, but if it does, Clapack is lighting is lightning fast.

Comment: I think is a pretty stupid question but, how I use it now? Where I can find some documentation?

Comment: [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack), or [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/single) for single precision routines

Comment: You need some sparse SVD library, like PROPACK, and to quantify what you mean by "rank". For such large matrices, the algebraic rank is virtually uncomputable (unless you happen to have a particularly well conditioned matrix), and thus you have to fix some cutoff. Can we have background on where the matrices come from ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) library supports sparse matrices, try it out.

Comment: Consider improving your answer by providing some sample source code to demonstrate the Eigen library's capabilities.

Comment: I am not a specialist of sparse matrix computation, but the OP should be able to see if it matches his requirements on this page:http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialSparse.html

Comment: Just checked the link, got broken, here is the new: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__SparseQuickRefPage.html

Answer (score 1):

Computing the algebraic rank is O(n^3), where n is the matrix size, so it's inherently slow. You need eg. to perform pivoting, and this is slow and inaccurate if your matrix is not well conditioned (for n = 4096, a typical matrix is *very ill conditioned*).

Now, what is the rank ? It is the dimension of the image. It is very difficult to compute when n is large and it'll be spoiled by any small numerical inaccuracy of the input. For n = 4096, unless you happen to have particularly well conditioned matrices, this will prevent you from doing anything useful with a pivoting algorithm.

The best way is in fact to fix a cutoff epsilon, compute the singular values s_1 > ... > s_n and take as the rank the lowest integer r such that sum(s_i^2, i > r) < epsilon^2 * sum(s_i^2).

You thus need a sparse SVD routine, eg. from [there](http://tedlab.mit.edu/~dr/SVDLIBC/).

This may not be faster, but to the very least it will be **correct**.

You can ask for less singular values that you need to speed up things. This is a tough problem, and with no info on the background and how you got these matrices, there is nothing more we can do.

Comment: They're binary matrices. They're build so that on a row they have 16 one e 4080 zeroes. In particulary every 256 numbers one is a 1 and the other 0. The positions of the "1" are generated randomly.

Comment: @Randomguy: You should have specified this. By mentioning you used armadillo, I inferred that you were manipulating floating point matrices. At this point, I think you have to look for some specific algorithm, perhaps asking math.stackexchange.com. See eg. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95219/parallel-rank-computation-of-huge-sparse-matrices-over-the-binary-field for some pointers (in the comments)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code (the documentation is here). 
It is an example for calculating the rank of the matrix A with Eigen library:

```
MatrixXd A(2,2);
A << 1 , 0, 1, 0;
FullPivLU<MatrixXd> luA(A);
int rank = luA.rank();
```